# 'invocation failed' and 'setups were not matched' at the same time

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I'm writting some unit tests and mocking some parts. I understand both the meanings of these errors seperately. My problem is that they occur at the same time and for the same method, but I can mock other methods of the same class. It's just that one particular method.

I already checked if:

1. there is confusion with different namespaces and same class names
2. there are methods with same names but different signatures
3. the mocking is happening after the method call. This is how the test looks like. I use the same structure for other methods of the same class and there is no problem:

   ```
   private readonly Mock<IDependency> mockDependency;

   [Fact]
   public void GetSomeThingByIdTest()
   {
       SetupMock();
       ITestedInterface testedClass = CreateTestedImpl();
       ISomeThing expected = new SomeThing();
       ISomeThing mocked = testedClass.GetSomeThingById("someId");

       Assert.Equal(expected, mocked);
   }

   private void SetupMock()
   {
       var mockSomeThing = new Mock<ISomeThing>();
       mockDependency.Setup(x => x.GetSomeThingById("someId")).Returns(mockSomeThing.Object);
   }

   private ITestedInterface CreateTestedImpl() => new Tested(mockDependency.Object);
   ```

I get:

Moq.MockException
ITestedInterface.GetSomeThingById(someId) invocation failed with mock behavior Strict.

and

Moq.MockException
The following setups were not matched:
ITestedInterfacex => x.GetSomeThingById(someId)

at the same time.
Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. There is not enough details in the question in its current state,

Comment: Those exceptions do not match the code example provided. For one no `Verify` is being called and no mock is being created with `Strict` behavior.